# Access properties file in same jar

Tags: java, jar, properties, classpath

All our jars contain a certain file `version.properties` which contains specific information from the build.

When we start a jar from command line (with several jars on the class path), we would like access the `version.properties` from *the same* jar. To be more precise: We would like to write Java code that gives us the content of the properties file in the jar where the calling class file resides.

The problem is that all jars on the class path contain `version.properties` and we do not want to read the first on the class path but the one from the correct jar. How can we achieve that?

Comment: Java uses packages for a good reason. Why don't you set version.properties in the appropriate package?

Comment: version.properties lies in the main directory of each jar - this cannot be changed (company standard)

Comment: The you won't be able to use the class loader to do that. Instead, you'll have to use dirty tricks to find out the jar where a class comes from (if any), then open a jar input stream to that jar and look for the version.properties entry, then read this entry. Or you could change the company standard to make it a usable standard.

Comment: I cannot change the company standard (for 2000 different Java projects), but I can think about generating additional files that duplicate the information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny problem. You have to find the location of a representative class of the particular jar and use the result to build the URL for the properties file. I hacked together an example using String.class as example and access MANIFEST.MF in META-INF, since the rt.jar has no properties in it (at least a quick `jar tf rt.jar | grep properties` resulted in zero results)

```
    Class clazz = String.class;
    String name = clazz.getName().replace('.', '/') + ".class";
    System.out.println(name);
    String loc = clazz.getClassLoader().getResource(name).toString();
    System.out.println(loc);
    if (loc.startsWith("jar:file")) {
        String propertyResource = loc.substring(0, loc.indexOf('!')) + "!" + "/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF";
        InputStream is = new URL(propertyResource).openStream();
        System.out.println(propertyResource);
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(is);
        System.out.println(props.get("Implementation-Title"));
    }
```